# Performance gains from re-using web service client class instances

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-services, asmx

I am thinking about the scenario where hundreds of calls need to be made to the same web service in rapid succession, with differing parameters.  Both the client and the service are written in ASP.NET.  The client class is the one automatically generated from the WSDL.

Leaving aside the questions of whether to make asynchronous calls, use parallel threads, or whether the service can handle that many hits, I have a question about performance.

Re-using an instance of the web service client class for all the calls will save the cost of re-creating and tearing down the client instance for each call.  I already know that.  But are there any other performance advantages to re-using that instance?  Does anything about the communication with the service (or processing the results) run more quickly if the same instance of the client is used for every call?

Comment: Is this a legacy ASMX client (Add Web Reference), or a WCF client (Add Service Reference)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders  I believe it is a legacy ASMX client.  I am not 100% sure because it was actually generated by running the WSDL.EXE program against a .wsdl file rather than by using either method of adding service references.  (We received a copy of the WSDL in advance of being given a URL for the service.)  The service, however, is an ASMX service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating any dynamic client that can invoke any WSDL at runtime ? Otherwise it is not necessary to maintain a client instance in server. The client instance can not do anything on the server performance.

Comment: True; but can the client instance being reused have any effect on the speed at which the client can process results, such as deserializing XML?

Comment: Thank you for your response, though.  I appreciate it!